# Android Volley - how properly to handle an exception inside onResponse method

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm using very simple example trying to understand why my app stops without responding when I make an exception inside onResponse method after successfully completed Volley StringRequest. This is my example:

```
try {
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                    (urlRequest), new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    //It is ok untill now. 
                    //But if I make an exception here my app stops responding... why??
                    int i = Integer.valueOf("purposely caused error"); 
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //handle error here is easy...
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("VolleyError", ex.getMessage());
        }
```

At onResponse method I'm trying to catch an exception. If there is an exception my app just stops responding. If i try to do something it ends with message "Wait" and "Ok". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onResponse` method is in another thread, try to put a try/catch INSIDE the `onResponse` method.

Comment: Once I wrote it here and I saw my stupid mistake. Thanks.

Comment: If it worked please accept my answer (to add a green tick next to my answer) ;)